# Preference learning with Bayesian optimization

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process, optimization, bayesian-optimization

I want to learn parameter preferences of users for different algorithms. The users are queried for their preference for one of the visualizations generated from a pair of parameter configurations for an algorithm.

So I have some data, that contain a lot of tuples like $(X, Y, D)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are parameter configurations and $D = 1$, if $X$ is preferred to $Y$, otherwise $D = 0$.

From this data, I want to be somehow able to apply Bayesian optimization with Gaussian processes.

Does some implementation for that already exist?

Comment: By implementation you would mean code for a statistics package (which would be off-topic here) or a statistical procedure for your problem at hand?

Comment: Both would be welcome. A statistical procedure would be great, if some   code already exists for it, it would be even better.

Comment: Are your data discrete or continuous? More specifically, are X and Y real numbers or vectors or not?

Comment: X and Y are in R^n. So yes, they are vectors.

Comment: You speak about some optimization. What do you want to have optimal? The parameters of your visualization?

Comment: The visualization should only show the result of an algorithm (black box function) result given the parameters. So what should be optimized are the parameters of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not use the Bayesian optimization with Gaussian processes, but it could help. I would transform you data from three columns $(X,Y,D)$ just into columns of them $(A,B)$ containing pairs $(X,D)$ and $(Y,1-D)$. $A$ data are from $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B$ are binary.

Now, you can use a classification algorithm that would return the probabilities $P(B=0|A)$ and $P(B=1|A)$. Having them, you can maximize this
$$
\frac{P(B=1|A)}{P(B=0|A)}
$$
To find the adopting any optimization approach (gradient-based or evolutionary). This would maximize the probability that your $A^*$ will be better in comparison to any other $A$.

Comment: So, I tried this approach, and it seems to be Ok. I used logistic regression as an classifier. The problem is, that the algorithm converges too fast to a value and does not move an inch away from it again after it went there.
Do you perhaps have an idea how to improve the exploration a bit?